# Is there a tool to take css classes and make them inline?

Tags: html, css

This sounds very backwards, but I want to take existing CSS classes and make them inline in the element itself (The css styles and the html elements are in the same file).  There is a reason for this, for which I will not go into detail.

Example:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
   .p1 { height: 10px; }
</style>

<body>
<p class="p1">...</p> <!-- Remove class="p1" and replace with style="height: 10px;" -->
<p class="p1">...</p>
<p class="p1">...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind there can be *many* CSS classes, and many can belong to a single element.

**Edit:**  The reason I'm doing this is because (based on our client) we want to generate PDF documents from an HTML template.  The PDF tool we use does not work well with *external* CSS classes.

Comment: Is that detail somehow, related to overriding?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Wouldn't `.p1` class be repeated three times for each `<p/>`?

Comment: Just to know, what tool do you use that doesn't handle external style sheets well?

Comment: ITextSharp (used for generating HTML -> PDF conversions).  You can use external style sheets, but it's not trivial to get the library to use them correctly.  It's easiest, if possible, to just try to in-line style them for the PDF generation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/) ([The source available as well](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer/)) - it is a Ruby library that does just that (inlines CSS for HTML email - but the output isn't specific to HTML email - it should work just fine with your PDF document generator as well).

There is also [`lamson.html.HtmlMail`](http://lamsonproject.org/docs/html_email_generation.html) if you are using Python and there are a variety of Node.js libraries available to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

MailChimp has a page for this in their labs, the CSS Inliner - 
http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css

It does leave the class, however.